# Message is highlighted in blue in Modal box in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

We are using below code to populate the messages in a dialog box, when the message appears the message is highlighted in blue - it's like we selected the message using the mouse. i want it the messages not to select when it appears. Anybody can help me on this issue.

```
CDialog::OnInitDialog();
CFont *m_pFont = new CFont();
LOGFONT lf;
memset(&lf, 0,sizeof(LOGFONT));
lf.lfHeight = 16;        
lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
strncpy_s(lf.lfFaceName,"Arial",6);
m_pFont->CreateFontIndirectA(&lf);
GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetFont(m_pFont,TRUE);
 m_message.SetWindowTextA((LPCTSTR)Message);  
return TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The selection will be set to all the text whenever the edit box becomes the selected item. If the edit box is the first in the tab order, or if you tab to it or click on it, all the characters are selected. You can override this behavior by capturing the `EN_SETFOCUS` event and resetting the selection yourself:

```
void CMyDlg::OnEnSetfocusEdit1()
{
   m_edit1.SetSel(0, 0);    // or (-1, -1) to set the selection at the end
}
```

Comment: hi Mark, i am using Visual studio 2012 framwork, in this VC++ version there is no property called "SetSel" for GetDlgItem

Comment: @Amitav you have to cast the result to a `CEdit` first.

Comment: No, m_message and IDC_EDIT1 are different control of type CEdit

Comment: after SetWindowTextA, i did a call to m_message.SetSel(-1, -1); but still the message appears in highlighed text

Comment: @Amitav my answer was incorrect, sorry. I've replaced it with the correct information.